# Assembly FileNotFound in .NET Framework referenced by ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core v2.1 project which references a project that's .NET Framework 4.5.
This .NET Framework project references `System.Data.DataExtensions`.

When i call a certain method of the .NET Framework project, i get this exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."

To remove all doubt, the file exists in the path (and also this is the path stated in the assembly properties) :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

What am i missing here? Thank you.

EDIT: The called method is the third called method in the same class, and its code starts with this:

```
 var cardRecord = from row in CardsDataTables.CardDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     where row.Field<string>("ca_number") == cardNumber
                     select row;
```

Comment: You are giving a 4.5 version of the path when the error is talking about V4.0. Can you recheck with 4.0? I don't really know the precise content of Core v2.1 and which version of the framework are compatible, but here it clearly looks like a framework version issue

Comment: You mean changing the framework to 4.0? i cannot do that as this project references other projects with framework 4.5.
if you mean changing the assembly path to the v4.5 folder, im not sure how i can do that..

Comment: No I mean based on the error mesage, it is looking after C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll (but I may be wrong). I don't understand why it's looking after this version if you are using V4.5 everywhere but it's my first guess

Comment: Could only go around it by migrating the .net framework project to .net core and replaced all AsEnumerable() occurrences to Select().. not a real answer, but thats the only thing that worked for me..

Comment: ofc this is the answer. you can't simply reference framework libs in core, net standard runs on linux and mac as well, framework only on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions through NuGet Package in Core 2.1 web project.